# java the system can not find the file specified

Tags: java

I used Java to copy file but it appeared a exception (the system can not find the file specified).

The codes are

```
public static void copyFile(String sourceFile, String destFile){
    try {       
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        in.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The test codes

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = getFileName("D:/z/temp.txt");
    String target = "D:/tem.txt";
    copyFile(name, target);
}
```

the exception is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: temp.txt(the system can not find the file specified)`

1. The file 'temp.txt' is existence.
2. The path is right no problem.

I guess that is the problem of Permissions. who can come up with the answer thanks!

Comment: What permissions do you have?

Comment: What happens, if you change this `copyFile(name, target);` to this `copyFile("D:/tem.txt", target);`

Comment: What is this method `getFileName("D:/z/temp.txt");`? Which Java class does it belong to? or Is this a custom method of your own? Surely, it's curious you're invoking it without any object.

Comment: It's my fault,I just forgot the `getFileName()` returns only the name of file. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to see the method `getFileName()` to be sure, but based on the error message and the method name, I suspect the problem is just that this method returns only the name of the file, removing the path info, so that the file is, indeed, not found.

Comment: Yes,I found it,thank you,as you say,the `getFileName()` returns only the name of file. i just forgot it. thank you.